# Bitwise operators explanation

Tags: c++, operators, bitmask

If we have a bitmask -> "00101101"
and a variable i = 4

If we do this **(1 << i) | bitmask** then what will happen to the bitmask?

Thank you.

Comment: If you do `(1 <<i) + 69` what will happen to the 69?

Comment: @rondo the problem with your question is, that you'd just need a piece of paper and a pencil or fives lines of code to find out yourself.

Comment: rondo, from SJuan's example you have to understand what can happen to the _righthand side_ of an expression (the same goes for `a = b + 1`). I'm flagging this question as `unclear` during review, because you seem to ask a homework excersice while having no understanding of programming (or maybe you've formulated your question just unclear).

Answer (score 4):

Your question is:

> If we do this (1 << i) | bitmask then what will happen to the bitmask?

Well, `bitmask` is involved in a statement the side effects of which do not affect `bitmask` itself.

So, nothing happens to `bitmask`, it was and it remains `00101101`.

Answer (score 0):

So you have:

```
unsigned int i = 4;
```

and you do:

```
1 << i;
```

this shifts `1` over 4 binary bits, you then do:

```
i | bitmask;
```

this logically return an `unsigned int` with the 4th bit set plus all the `1` bits in `bitmask` (which remains untouched) set.

Answer (score 0):

i = 4, 1<<4 is shift left by 4 digits to one ====> reults 10000 ====> 16